# Which to use for algorithm parameters in C#: static, const, readonly?

Tags: c#, parameters, static, constants

I have some classes whose methods implement scientific, numeric algorithms.

For example, one class implements Radial-Basis-Function and need some parameters. Currently, they are like this:

```
public class Interpolator {

    // Free parameters
    static int LAYERS = 6;
    static int MINIMUM_NEIGHBORS = 1;
    static double SEARCH_RADIUS = 20;
    static double START_RADIUS = 100;

    (...)
}
```

The idea here is that these parameters will be determined experimentally, and ideally should not be changed, not even via configuration.

So the question is: which is the "right" way of declaring them? Should they actually be `static`? Shouldn't they be `const`? How this (rather common) pattern usually implemented regarding to good practices, in C#?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The idea here is that these parameters will be determined
>   experimentally, and ideally should not be changed, not even via
>   configuration

Just declare them as constant. `const`. Since constants are implicitly static, you can access them with your class name.

If you define them as static, then you can modify them as well.

```
public class Interpolator
{
    const int LAYERS = 6;
    const int MINIMUM_NEIGHBORS = 1;
    const double SEARCH_RADIUS = 20;
    const double START_RADIUS = 100;
}
```

Comment: Very useful info. But these variables are private, used only inside this class' methods.

Comment: @heltonbiker, if they are private then they are not accessible outside the class, but still having them as `const` would save you from accidental modification to any of those variables.

Comment: Nice, that's the idea. Even this project being programmed fully in-house, these accidental (buggy) modification you mention can happen anytime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To give a concise pragmatic answer:

`readonly` : Do you ever need to change them after they've been initialized?

`static` : Should they be accessible from other assemblies?

`const` : If you answered no to the previous two questions, use const.

Comment: That's not strictly correct.  `readonly static` isn't the same as `const`.  If it's `readonly static` then it is a varaible, and occupies a location in memory.  It can also be a non-literal value, and can even be generated at runtime (so long as it's not changed after it's initialized).  `const` means it's a *compile time constant* because it doesn't create a location in memory; the literal value is inlined everywhere the identifier is used.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use "values that won't change" you can declare fields either `const` or `static readonly`:

```
public class Interpolator 
{
  // Free parameters
  static readonly int LAYERS = 6;
  const int MINIMUM_NEIGHBORS = 1;
}
```

To decide for one or the other I use the following criteria:

- If it will be accessed only within this assembly (this project in Visual Studio), use `const`.
- If it could be accessed by other assembly, use `static readonly`.

Improving your example:

```
public class Interpolator 
{
  // Free parameters
  public static readonly int LAYERS = 6;
  internal const int MINIMUM_NEIGHBORS = 1; // internal means public to this assembly but private to other assemblies.
  private const double SEARCH_RADIUS = 20;
}
```

---

Why making that distinction?
When the compiler finds a `const` field in an expression, it substitutes the field by its value and compiles it. This is very efficient.

```
int a = 5 * Interpolator.SEARCH_RADIUS;
```

is compiled as:

```
int a = 100;
```

But imagine you have `Interpolator.SEARCH_RADIUS` defined as a `const` in an (.dll) assembly, and use it fron another (.exe) assembly.

```
public const double SEARCH_RADIUS = 20;
```

If, in the future, you changed the definition to

```
private const double SEARCH_RADIUS = 10;
```

and recompile your (.dll) assembly. If you don't recompile your (.exe) assembly, it would still be using `a==100`, because `SEARCH_RADIUS = 20` was the value it used during the .exe compilation.

If you had defined

```
public static readonly double SEARCH_RADIUS = 20;
```

in the .dll, when you change the value to `10` and recompile only the (.dll) assembly, the other (.exe) assembly would automatically get the change, without need to be recompiled.